# How to catch all the values which is returned by this program?

Tags: java

```
public class Test {

    static int nthDigit(int number, int n)
    {
        int digit = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) { // Assumes n is >= 0
            digit = number % 10;
            number /= 10;
        }

        return digit;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(nthDigit(2314, 4));
    }
}
```

Now output of this program is 0

When I perform unit testing it first returns 4 then 1,3,2 respectively.....

I don't know where I have done the mistake is there any other way to get the output 4,1,3,2
respectively....

Comment: Do you want a string output? Getting the first 4 digits? I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do:

```
return new Integer(String.valueOf(number).substring(n-1,n));
```

Comment: Good, except that you should do `n-1, n` because string indexes start at 0. For example, if `n` was 4, an exception would be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

The error in your code is in the return statement/ or your use of it.

```
digit = number % 10;
```

If what you want is for the string 4 3 2 1  to be written to the output stream, then you probably want to do this

```
 static String nthDigit(int number, int n)
    {
        String digit = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) { // Assumes n is >= 0
            digit += (number % 10).ToString();
            number /= 10;
        }

        return digit;
    }
```

Notice I changed the return type of the method, and I changed the operator used to populate digit from '=' to '+=' to ensure all values are captured.

If it is the case that you instead want the sum of the values returned, then you would change your code like so

```
 static int nthDigit(int number, int n)
    {
        int digit = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) { // Assumes n is >= 0
            **digit += number % 10;**
            number /= 10;
        }

        return digit;
    }
```

I revert the int return type back to what you originally had, but I keep the operator change I had made earlier.

Answer (score 0):

```
static int nthDigit(int number, int n)
{
    n = String.valueOf(number).length() - n;
    int digit = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        digit = number % 10;
        number /= 10;
    }
    return digit;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println(nthDigit(2314, 1)); // 2
    System.out.println(nthDigit(2314, 2)); // 3
    System.out.println(nthDigit(2314, 3)); // 1
    System.out.println(nthDigit(2314, 4)); // 4
}
```

What I did was instead of starting with n as the n<sup>th</sup> digit, I had it start at the opposite side of the number to it. So instead of the 4<sup>th</sup> digit, I would have used the 1<sup>st</sup> digit. To do that, I subtracted `n` from the length of the number (that's the complement of it, if you've ever taken a probability course).